# public free hotspot access by login or payment

Tags: wifi

There are a lot of public places that suggest connection to internet via free wifi by login to website or payment. I try to figure out how this work. Do I need server or the web page can run on router? What technology or software do I need? Is anyone can shed light on it?

Answer (score 2):

What you're referring to is [Captive Portal](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal)

> The captive portal technique forces an HTTP client on a network to see
>   a special web page (usually for authentication purposes) before using
>   the Internet normally. A captive portal turns a Web browser into an
>   authentication device. This is done by intercepting most packets,
>   regardless of address or port, until the user opens a browser and
>   tries to access the web. At that time the browser is redirected to a
>   web page which may require authentication and/or payment, or simply
>   display an acceptable use policy and require the user to agree.
>   Captive portals are used at many Wi-Fi hotspots, and can be used to
>   control wired access (e.g. apartment houses, hotel rooms, business
>   centers, "open" Ethernet jacks) as well.